# How to prevent JSTL c:out from replacing numeric character references with one-byte characters

Tags: utf-8, jstl, character, rendering

Hello and thank you for reading my post.

I am working on a Java Dynamic Web Project with Tomcat7.

My problem is about how "c:out" renders numeric character references in JSPs.

In "web.xml", I have the following "context-param":

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>S_IF_MSG_USER_INFO_MY_ACCOUNT_4</param-name>
  <param-value>d&#233;marrer un nouveau ticket,</param-value>
</context-param>
```

In a JSP "foo.jsp", I have the following "c:out":

```
<c:out value="${initParam['S_IF_MSG_USER_INFO_MY_ACCOUNT_4']}"></c:out>
```

If I request the JSP "foo.jsp" in a browser and have a look at the source code of the resulting page, the string `d&#233;marrer un nouveau ticket,` has been replaced with `démarrer un nouveau ticket,`
meaning the numeric character reference `&#233;` has been replaced with the character `é` (one byte 0xE9).

I do not want this to happen.
In particular, because if the Web browser character encoding is changed manually (by default it is UTF8) to "Western ISO-8859-1" I get the two bytes Ã© (0xC3 0xA9) instead of é. This was indeed predictable but this exactly is what I was trying to avoid by using numeric character references.

What can I do? Where did I got mixed up?
Best regards.

EDIT 1

I also tried without the "c:out":

`${initParam['S_IF_MSG_USER_INFO_MY_ACCOUNT_4']}` directly.

Unfortunately, it also transforms the `&#233;` into `é`.

Answer (score 0):

I added a method `escapeCharactersWithAnAccute()` to my project.

This method takes a string as an input and returns the string with the characters in this set http://www.sagehill.net/livedtd/xhtml1-transitional/xhtml-lat1.ent.html replaced by their numeric character reference.

Then, in the JSP, if I write things like below, I get the expected result:

```
<c:out escapeXml="false" value="${isd_fun:escapeCharactersWithAnAccute(initParam['S_IF_MSG_USER_INFO_MY_ACCOUNT_4'])}"></c:out>
```